# Do linear algebra packages accept matrix elements that are infinite or other number-like input?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, lapack, blas, eigenvalue

### Background

I'm doing research about stability analysis of some dynamical system. In the literature, others have used analytical methods to query the signs of the eigenvalues of the linearized system matrix. My approach is to use a numerical eigenvalue solver. In some cases, input to the stability analysis consists of some coefficients that become infinite. In the analytical approach, this is tackled by taking the limit of the resulting stability criteria to infinity. "Taking the limit" is however not possible in a numerical approach, so I have reformulated the problem to avoid infinite coefficients in my numerical implementation.

### Question

Now my question should be clear. Would a linear algebra package allow to use infinite coefficients? My direct application only needs eigenvalue solvers, but I don't want to narrow down to that. Any answer regarding infinite coefficients as input to linear algebra algorithms (matrix-solve, eigenvalue problem, singular value decomposition, LU etc.) is welcome.